# Why my HTTP server receives only the first GET request

Tags: c++, http, get, httpserver

I want to write my own server using native C/C++ sockets that will answer on browser's HTTP GET requests. I wrote all the code needed for server to receive something from client, and it works. Well, for the first GET request...
When I open browser and go to localhost, browser successfully connects to the server, and sends it such request.

GET / HTTP/1.1
Then, my server sends response with simplest standard html page, that contains text and a link to style.css file. After that, browser sends a request for style.css 
GET /style.css HTTP/1.1
But it already doesn't come to the server, it just disappears somewhere. DevTools in Chrome tells me that the request was sent, and it waits for a respond, but server receives completely nothing, no matter what was requested(JS files, favicon.ico, etc) and I can't really solve this problem myself. I wonder if this is related to my code at all. 
Here is minimal reproduction of the code.

```
    WSADATA wsaData;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "WSAStartup failed. Aborting.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Initialized.\n";

    int client;
    int server;
    client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(15742);

    bind(client, reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr*>(&server_addr), sizeof(server_addr));
    std::cout << "Binding done\n";

    listen(client, 1);

    int size = sizeof(server_addr);
    std::cout << "Waiting to accept a client\n";
    server = accept(client, reinterpret_cast<struct sockaddr*>(&server_addr), &size);
    std::string HTTPresponseBase;
    std::string responsehtml;
    std::string responsecss;
    constexpr size_t buff_size = 2048;
    char buffer[buff_size] = { 0 };

    HTTPresponseBase = R"response(HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n)response";

    std::string html = R"html(<html>
  <head>
    <title>An Example Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p class="header">Hello World, this is a very simple HTML document.</p>
  </body>
</html>)html";

    std::string css = R"css(
.header{
    color: red;
}
)css";
    responsehtml = HTTPresponseBase;
    responsehtml += html;

    responsecss = HTTPresponseBase;
    responsecss += css;

    std::string message;
    if (server > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Connected to web-browser\n";

        while (true) {
            recv(server, buffer, buff_size, 0);
            if (buffer[0] == 0)
                continue;
            std::cout << "Client:\n" << buffer << '\n';
            if(strstr(buffer, "GET / "))
                send(server, responsehtml.c_str(), responsehtml.size() + 1, 0);
            else if (strstr(buffer, "GET /style.css"))
                send(server, responsecss.c_str(), responsecss.size() + 1, 0);
            std::cout << "Response sent\n";

            memset(buffer, 0, buff_size);
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could use a network monitor like wireshark to see the actual packages between browser and server. One thing to note is whether the browser keeps the same connection after the first request or starts a new one, because that is not handled by the server (default in http 1.1 is keeping same connection)

Comment: Also,  unless you see it as cheating, a little help from a library may help you: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links/libs (see communication).

Comment: @stefaanv Added an std::thread to listen to connections on background and no connection was established too, so problem is not related to this.
For now, will try Wireshark, thank you!